# Datastore does not return any result when cursor pointing to entity gets updated but retains its position in list

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using google datastore to get data of a user:

This is what i'm trying to do:

1. When data is updated, its `updated_at [indexed]` property gets set to current timestamp.
2. I query data on `updated_at` in ***ascending order*** and **store cursor** returned for later use.
3. Now user has updated the last entity (which cursor points currently) and **no other data is added or updated**.
4. Now i'm expecting that last entity to be returned in next query (using that old cursor) because it was updated and now has a new `updated_at` timestamp.
5. But that is not the case, i do not see that (my result is empty list) And now i have lost that update completely because query will return all the other object except that last entity that was updated.

Am I doing something wrong or is this the way it is? If this is natural behavior then what is a preferred way to get the last entity that was updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclosure** This answer represent just my understanding how GAE datastore works. Reality can be different. But the solution should work anyway.

You can think of a cursor as a pointer to a node in linked list.
Basically it's storing just query used to get it and a key to the "last/current" entity. When entities updated in datastore it has no way to update a cursor.

When you change entity's field `updated_at` it does not change the key stored at cursor. So if you update filtred/ordered properties the old cursor points to the same node but in a different "chain".

**Solution**: Instead of storing cursor you can store the last (*max*) `updated_at` and query your data with `.filter('updated_at >', last_updated_at)`. This way you will:

1. Get your entity in the results if updated_at changed (increased)
2. Have smaller & more readable "cursor" to pass around.

Comment: Making queries based on timestamp can cause issues in those edge cases where two entries have same `updated_at`.

Comment: Sure, but it depends on data. For example same user can't add 2 comments at very same time. Or even different users if there is a transactional lock.

Comment: Remember also that any query may not immediately reflect the updated entity as the indexes the query are dependent on may not have been updated yet due to Eventual Consitency

Comment: Sure, and for that purpose if you care about consistency for changed entities you would pass an IDs of such entities, get them by ID and merge with query results. That's the price for distributed DB & eventual consistency.

Answer (score 1):

Think of datastore cursors as pointing "between" entities, as in "Here's where to continue the scan."

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/query-cursors) says "... a cursor, which is an opaque base64-encoded string marking the index position of the last result retrieved," but that last result won't be re-retrieved.

Comment: So, what will happen in this condition. currently last item at cursor is an entity (call it `entity1`) and if a new item is added with greater `updated_at` (call it `entity2`) but then again entity1's `updated_at` is increased (now it has greatest `updated_at` again). Will the cursor query return `entity2` in next query or not?

Comment: If by "greater than" you mean one that would follow entity1 using the same query, then the new entity will be picked up when you apply the same search criteria plus the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

It is the expected behaviour, because the data was modified between the moment when the cursor was created and when it is used. From [Cursors and data updates](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/query-cursors#cursors_and_data_updates):

> ... If the results for a query change between uses of a cursor, the
>   query notices only changes that occur in results **after** the cursor.
>   ...